# Using the exec() family to run the "cd" command

Tags: c, linux, shell, exec

I know that `cd` is a shell built-in ,and I can run it by using `system()`.

But is that possible to run the `cd` command by the `exec()` family, like `execvp()`?

Edit: And I just noticed that `system("cd")` is also meaningless。Thanks for the help of everyone.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`exec` loads an *executable file* and replaces the current program image with it. As you rightly noted, `cd` is *not* an executable file, but rather a shell builtin. So the executable that you want to run is the shell itself. This is of course what `system()` does for you, but if you want to be explicit about it, you can use `exec`:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "-c", "cd", (const char *)0);
```

Since this *replaces* your current process image, you should do this after `fork()`ing off a new process.

However, this entire procedure has absolutely no effect. If you want to change the directory in your current process, use `chdir()`.

Comment: Can you walk through what the argument represent?

Comment: @User: The arguments make up the command that's being executed, and since this is a variable-argument function, we have to signal the end of the arguments somehow, which in this case is done by a null pointer of type `const char *`. So the command that's executed is: `/bin/sh -c cd`

Answer (score 12):

You're better off using `int chdir(const char *path);` found in `unistd.h`.

Answer (score 3):

No it is not, and it would be of no use. `chdir` (the function that changes a process's current directory) only affects the process that calls it (and its children). It does not affect its parent in particular.

So `exec`ing `cd` has no point, since the process would exit immediately after having changed directories.

(You could exec something like `bash -c cd /tmp` if you really want to, but as I said, this is fruitless.)

Answer (score 3):

While, as already stated `system("cd xxx")` wouldn't change your application current directory, it is not completely useless.

You can still use system exit status to know if changing your current directory to the one stated would succeed or not.

Similarly, if you like complex solutions, you could also do the same with fork/exec, either with exec'ing `/bin/sh -c cd xxx` or simply `/bin/cd xxx` with OSes that provide an independent `cd` executable.

I would however recommend this non overkill faster equivalent `access("xxx", X_OK|R_OK)`

Note: All POSIX compliant OSes **[must](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06)** provide an independent cd executable. This is at least the case with [Solaris](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1461/cd-1.html#scrolltoc), [AIX](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/pseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/cd.htm), HP-UX and [Mac OS/X](http://lists.apple.com/archives/Darwin-userlevel/2005/May/msg00031.html).

Comment: A independent `cd` executable is just and plain impossible.

Comment: There is definitely one on the OS I'm using.

Comment: @jliagre: Backup the last paragraph with pointers.  E.g. link to the end of http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html where it is said that *all of the standard utilities, including the regular built-ins [...], shall be implemented in a manner so that they can be accessed via the exec family of functions*.  And to Solaris's cd man http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/816-5165/6mbb0m9bl/index.html that states */usr/bin/cd has no effect on the invoking process but can be used to determine whether or not a given directory can be set as the current directory*

Answer (score 0):

When a fork is done the environment variable CWD(current working directory) is inherited by the child from the parent.If fork and exec is done as usual then the child calls chdir() which simply changes the directory to the new directory and exits but this does not affect the parent.Hence, the new environment is lost..