# How to use exec() family to implement the shell commands cp and rm?

Tags: linux, exec

how can I implement cp and rm shell commands using exec() family system calls ? I've searched a lot but did'nt find any helpful site/link ,can someone help please ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the exec() family to run the "cd" command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859903/using-the-exec-family-to-run-the-cd-command)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Not really, because `cd` is a shell built-in.

Comment: @Barmar: Yes, you're right, `cp` and `rm` are not builtin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's are examples.

The `exec` functions with `l` in their name take the list of arguments as their own arguments. The `p` suffix means that the command should be found using `$PATH`, so you can just supply the command name.

```
execlp("cp", "cp", "sourcefile", "destfile", (char *)0);
```

The variants with `v` take the argument in a single array argument ("v" stands for `vector`). In this case, I didn't use the `e` suffix, so I gave the full path to the program.

```
char *args[] = {"rm", "file1", "file2", 0);
execv("/bin/rm", args);
```

In both cases, the first argument is also the name of the program, since this will become `argv[0]` in the new process. And the end of arguments is signified with a null pointer. You should provide the typecast explicitly when using the `l` variants, since varargs functions don't do automatic type conversion to pointers.